# How to access create query method in symfony repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the class user repository

```
class userRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    function getuserData($id)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery('
                SELECT c FROM AcmeBundle:User c 
                WHERE c.id = :id ORDER BY c.id ASC
            ')
            ->setParameter('id', $id);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

> Undefined method 'createQuery'. The method name must start with either
>   findBy or findOneBy!

Answer (score 10):

According to [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql)

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p 
        WHERE p.price > :price 
        ORDER BY p.price ASC
    ')
    ->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Now i get this error  `Call to a member function createQuery() on a non-object`

Comment: Probably it appears in another place

Comment: sorry i didn't get what u mean

Comment: This error probably appears in another place, not in `$em-createQuery()`

Comment: no no it was there only , if i remove those lines then page work ok

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is quite late but your userRepository class needs to be defined in your User entity.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="NameOfBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
class User
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we work at Repositories

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager(); //wont work in repository
$em->createQueryBuilder($sql);
```

you have to use

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();     
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

[Read More](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The method `CreateQuery` is of **Entity Manager**, is not `Controller`'s class